# Getting error when adding platform in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

config file *-Info.plist requested for changes not found at /home/personal/Documents/app/platforms/browser/*-Info.plist, ignoring

Does anyone know what could be causing this? The path for the Info.plist file is incorrect. How do I generate one to remove this warning/error?

BR,

Comment: Can you show us the command you're trying to use to add a platform?  Is that the entire message you see when trying to add the platform?

Comment: And the command used to create the app, and what cordova cli version you have installed.

Comment: I am getting the same error and the command I am using is:

cordova build android --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --release --max_old_space_size=4096

I started seeing this eror as soon as I upgraded my android version in cordova to 7.1.1

Comment: Getting this error from running `ionic cordova run browser`